# Error trying modify some attributes of a database table in a controller C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I´m trying to modify attributes using sql database and web api .Net 6

In a controller i have this method

```
private void SetRefreshToken(RefreshToken newRefreshToken)
{

            newRefreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken();

            //...

            user.RefreshToken = newRefreshToken.Token;
            user.TokenCreated = newRefreshToken.Created;
            user.TokenExpires = newRefreshToken.Expires;

            _context.Update(user.RefreshToken);
            _context.Update(user.TokenCreated);
            _context.Update(user.TokenExpires);

            _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'string' was not found.

            //This error occurs if is _context.Update(user)
            //System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
}
```

And I have two models, an User who have some attributes + refreshtoken + Token Created + Token Expires
And a Refresh Token Model who have the refreshtoken + Token Created + Token Expires

How I can update some data of a table and get rid of this errors?

Comment: Where/how is `_context` initialized? where does `user` come from? Please add some details to your question, and if possible a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @anastaciu , _context comes from " private readonly AppDbContext _context " and user comes from " public static User user = new User() "

Comment: So how would _context know what user to update? Try @MichaelK solution.

Comment: Note that `private readonly AppDbContext _context` still needs to be initialized, I'm assuming that it's done so via DI.

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving user from database and then populating with new values and save the changes to context.

```
   var user = await _context.users.Where(b => b.id.Equals(user_id).FirstOrDefaultAsync());
 
    if (user is not null)
    {
    user.RefreshToken = newRefreshToken.Token;
    user.TokenCreated = newRefreshToken.Created;
    user.TokenExpires = newRefreshToken.Expires;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```